# Swift predicate only matches first value in array of values

Tags: arrays, swift, nspredicate, ckquery, ckqueryoperation

I have a class `Download` that serves as a wrapper for `CKQueryOperation`. One of the inits allows me to build my predicate with an array of values:

```
init(type: String, queryField: String, queryValues: [CKRecordValue], to rec: RecievesRecordable, from database: CKDatabase? = nil) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(queryField) = %@", argumentArray: queryValues)
    query = CKQuery(recordType: type, predicate: predicate)

    reciever = rec
    db = database

    super.init()
}
```

When I test it, `query` only matches the first value in the array. So if `queryValues = [testValue0, testValue1]` and I have one record whose field matches `testValue0` and I have a second record that matches `testValue1`, only the first record will be discovered. If I switch the order, than the other record gets recognized.

It seems weird that **I can create a predicate with an array but only the first value gets matched.** The documentation says that values are substituted in the order they appear, but **shouldn't it still be moving on to the second value?**

For more context, each record is stored in a separate database (private vs public) and my `Download` class launches two separate `CKQueryOperations` that both rely on `query`, if `database` param is left nil. **Whichever op fails ends up finding no results that match the first value and then giving up before checking the second value.**

I can include the full code for 'Download' and my failing unit test if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong predicate. You want to use the `IN` operation. And instead of using string substitution for the field name, use the `%K` format specifier:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@", arguments: queryField, queryValues)
```

Note that the `NSPredicate(format:argumentArray:)` expects there to be one format specifier in the format string for each value in the argument array. Since your format only had one format specifier, only the first value was taken from the array. And since you used `=`, the field was simply compared against that one value.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me. I'm away from my code atm, but this makes a lot of sense. I'll accept this answer once I get a chance to confirm it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> **Basic Comparisons**
> =, == The left-hand expression is equal to the right-hand expression.
>
> > =, => The left-hand expression is greater than or equal to the right-hand expression. <=, =< The left-hand expression is less than or
> > equal to the right-hand expression.
> > The left-hand expression is greater than the right-hand expression. < The left-hand expression is less than the right-hand expression. !=,
> > <> The left-hand expression is not equal to the right-hand expression.
>
> **String Comparisons**

> BEGINSWITH The left-hand expression begins with the right-hand
> expression.
>
> CONTAINS The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.
>
> ENDSWITH The left-hand expression ends with the right-hand expression.
>
> LIKE The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and
>
> - are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.
>
> MATCHES The left hand expression equals the right hand expression
> using a regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details
> see the ICU User Guide for Regular Expressions).

**I used Basic Comparisons**

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "key", "value")
let result_filtered = MYARRAY.filtered(using: resultPredicate) as NSArray
```

[*More information : Predicate Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it